# why use ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

which is the utility of using ubuntu touch, if it only serves to high-end smartphones?
are doing the same as the android ? only updating the new phones to force people to consume their new mobiles and trow away the old mobiles in the trash ?
the mobile galaxy nexus x is already considered obsolete and i only find work carried forr the new nexus..
i had imagined that ubuntu touch will also serve for mobiles low-end, but it seems that when there is $ involved, forget the principles

Right now, i'm tryn to develope ubuntu touch for moto e XT1023 but i are ALONE with this project, because all the xda are more concerned about the fact receive or not the new lollipop

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than an actual question, and even then your headline question is begging for opinion based answers, which are against this website policy, please reformulate.

Comment: Read again: why use ubuntu touch if are the same as Android?

Comment: well, obviously people here are ubuntu anthousiasts, so they'll certainly come up with reasons, but one person's favourite feature might be another's annoyance. You see what I mean? You say you are porting UT to another smartphone (thank you for doing that btw), so surely you have your opinion already on the OS. I am personally very interested in UT too, but I am not sure this question should be asked here. It probably belongs to a blog post, or a place like Slashdot, HN or reddit.

Comment: Opinion based question. Flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose UT because of working terminal and userland terminal applications it allows me to use out of box.

With Android I had to install some intermediate software like "Lil Debi", then through it to create container file, then download into it all the Debial userland and additional software I wanted to use. Now this container file was limited to 2GB size, so not much additional software fit into it. Sure I could figure that out but never managed to do it. Then to get to Debian command prompt I had to start the 'Lil Debi' app, click "mount and start debian" button, click "Open Terminal" button, manually delete with keyboard some garbage text from terminal line which appeared in new terminal, then start `/debian/shell` and there was problem with this script because on my 4.4 Cyanogen it failed to pass environment variables to Debian chroot environment, so more hassle with that too. Then I could finally run my `emacs` and start using this application in terminal mode. Then this setup was eating battery even when idle (even with all `prevent wifi/system/screen/etc` disabled in Lil Debi settings). I had my tablet left in sleep mode with idle Lil Debi command prompt and over night I've got full deep discharge from initial ~30% charge. Then non-latin symbols in terminal were not correctly displayed. Sure I could figure this out too - just more time wasted. And the above setup does not seem to work under latest Lollipop Android version - Lil Debi just fails to create/mount contained for Debial chroot environment. Sure this will sometimes be fixed and I could stay on Android 4.4, but still.

Now with Ubuntu touch I have working terminal out of box. It supports non-latin characters correctly out of box. It does not seem to consume excessive amount of power. It is only limited by the total storage memory of my device, not by 2GB chroot container file. And its terminal supports cursor movement top/down by screen swipes. And it allows me to customise the special keyboard shortcuts in its bar so I have all the CTRL-X, CTRL-@ and such even without physical keyboard attached. This allows me to use emacs with just virtual keyboard just OK. Sure not for extended sessions but good for quick picking into the data.

Yay! Ubuntu Touch seems good enough for me as terminal machine. So on my Nexus 7 I prefer running Ubuntu Touch and not Android anymore. Yes, my need is specific and not mass-market, but I am happy with Ubuntu Touch!